# Regex to find double whitespace not on the start of a line

Tags: regex, code-formatting, removing-whitespace, negative-lookbehind

I'm struggling with old "formatted" code, where a lot of whitespace is added to line up ='s and so on:

```
  if (!This.RevData.Last().Size() eq 0) then
    !DocRev   = '?'
    !Status   = '?'
    !RevCode  = '?'
  else
    !Pad      = !This.RevData.Last()[1]
    !DocRev   = !Pad[2]
    !Status   = !This.GenUtil.If((!Pad[3] eq 'UA'), '' , !Pad[3])
    !RevCode  = !This.GenUtil.If((!Pad[6] eq ''  ), '?', !Pad[6])
  endif
```

In this example it actually makes some sense, but most often the code have been modified to a state that makes the whitespace much more *confusing* than *helpful*.

What I'd like to do is to replace all double (or more) whitespaces with a single space, but I'd of course like to keep the indenting. Hence I'm looking for a regex to identify double (or more) spaces that are not at the start of the line. I've tried [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but can't seem to make it work:

```
(?<![\n])[\s]{2,}
```

Any hints, anyone? Ohh, and I'm using Ultraedit (the Perl regex engine), so the regex should be "UE-compatible".

**EDIT**: UE doesn't evaluate regex's line for line; newlines is just a character in the long string that is the document, which complicates the problem a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace "`([^ \n] ) +`" with "`$1`".  No funky lookbehinds required.

Comment: As I said in the comment for @non-descript, `[^ ]` matches newlines as well in UE, which leaves me without indenting at all...

Comment: Great, that worked! I had to use one space between ) and +, and one space trailing $1. Without the trailing space, every multispace was replaced with no spaces. Thanks!

Comment: Somebody tried to edit this to `(\S)  +`. That's roughly equivalent if your regex engine supports PCRE, but I like to keep this answer general.

Answer (score 2):

It's not PCRE but this will do what you need if you have access to a Linux shell:

```bash
sed s/"\([^ ]\) \+"/"\1 "/g source.code > reformatted.code
```

It will just replace any spaces that follow a non-space character while preserving that character. Should be easy enough to perlify it, if you're used to Perl Regexs.

Comment: What you instruct sed to search for here is `([^ ]) +`, right? In UE, the newline character will qualify as `[^ ]`, which makes it replace whitespaces on the start of the line as well.

Comment: [^ ] means "anything but a space" in POSIX regex. Afaik it's the same in Perl. http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/regular_expressions.html says: to do the same in UE you'd have to use a "~" instead of the "^".

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing...

```
(?<=[^\r\n])([\t ])[\t ]*
```

with...

```
$1
```

Comment: This lets me keep only the first three whitespaces of indenting.